# How can apply multiple background color to one div

Tags: html, css

I've some scenario where I should use multiple background color to one div. It's better for me rather than using background images or additional div. But, I can't find easier way to use it by CSS. So, I need help about some scenario. Please, see the image:

[image]

(1) I want to build "A". for that I wrote:

```
div.A { background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c9e9f, #f6f6f6); }
```

But, after writing that code, it'll like "B". But, I want exactly like "A". So, by css/css3 how can I do it(without adding more divs)?

(2) Is it possible to make one portion smaller than other portion? For example, at "C", blue color is smaller(at height) than the other portion. How, can I apply multiple background color to one div with making one portion smaller like "C"(without adding additional divs to "C")?

Update:
After @Mohammad's answer, I've tried with that way. But, for "C" scenario, I can't decrease the height of blue portion. Can you please, tell me how can I do it? 
jsfiddle.net/mFjQ6

Comment: you're better off using another container element, if you don't want extra markup you may want to use a pseudo-element i.e. using `:before` or `:after` though the effectiveness of that will depend on if and what content you want to place on the div sections

Comment: Basically, I had more complex scenario, at that scenario, I need linear gradiant as well as :before :after. But, the concept of :before and :after hadn't come to my mind at first. Thanks to remember me.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The A div can actually be made without `:before` or `:after` selector but using linear gradient as your first try. The only difference is that you must specify 4 positions. Dark grey from 0 to 50% and ligth grey from 50% to 100% like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#f6f6f6 50%,#f6f6f6 100%);
```

As you know, B div is made from a linear gradient having 2 positions like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#f6f6f6 100%);
```

For the C div, i use the same kind of gradient as div A ike this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%);
```

But this time i used the `:after` selector with a white background like if the second part of your div was smaller. *** *Please note that I added a better alternative below.***

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcsM2/) or the snippet below for complete cross-browser code.

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    height:100px;
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.a{
    background: #9c9e9f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #f6f6f6 50%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(50%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(50%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#f6f6f6 50%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#f6f6f6 50%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#f6f6f6 50%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#f6f6f6 50%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.b{
    background: #9c9e9f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.c{    
    background: #9c9e9f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #33ccff 50%, #33ccff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(50%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(50%,#33ccff), color-stop(100%,#33ccff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#33ccff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.c:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
```

---

There is also an alternative for the C div without using a white background to hide the a part of the second section.
Instead, we make the second part transparent and we use the `:after` selector to act as a colored background with the desired position and size.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcsM2/129/) or the snippet below for this updated solution.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.a {
  background: #9c9e9f;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #f6f6f6 50%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #9c9e9f), color-stop(50%, #9c9e9f), color-stop(50%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(100%, #f6f6f6));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #f6f6f6 50%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #f6f6f6 50%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #f6f6f6 50%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #f6f6f6 50%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#f6f6f6', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.b {
  background: #9c9e9f;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #9c9e9f), color-stop(100%, #f6f6f6));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c9e9f 0%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#f6f6f6', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.c {
  background: #9c9e9f;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #9c9e9f), color-stop(50%, #9c9e9f), color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#ffffff00', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.c:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #33ccff;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could apply both background-color and border to make it look like 2 colors.

```
div.A { width: 50px; background-color: #9c9e9f; border-right: 50px solid #f6f6f6; }
```

The border should have the same size as the width.

Comment: OP wants a different size in height, not width

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, my answer is for his question #1, not for the C scenario.

Comment: If that's the case then width and border should be of same size

Comment: It's not possible to solve my need with using border. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for misunderstanding, from what I understood you want your DIV to have three different colors with different heights. This is the output of my code:

[image: output],

If this is what you want try this code:

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width:400px;
    position: relative;
}
.c {
    background: blue; /* Old browsers */
}

.c:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:20%;
    left:0;
    height:110%;
    background: yellow;
}
.c:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:40%;
    left:60%;
    height:140%;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="c"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is compatible with all the browsers, change values to fit your application

```
background: #fdfdfd;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd 0%, #f6f6f6 60%, #f2f2f2 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fdfdfd), color-stop(60%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#f2f2f2));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd 0%,#f6f6f6 60%,#f2f2f2 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd 0%,#f6f6f6 60%,#f2f2f2 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd 0%,#f6f6f6 60%,#f2f2f2 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfdfd 0%,#f6f6f6 60%,#f2f2f2 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fdfdfd', endColorstr='#f2f2f2',GradientType=0
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the needs of the OP

Comment: It can be okay for me. But, for "C" scenario, I can't decrease the height of blue portion. Can you please, tell me how can I do it?
http://jsfiddle.net/mFjQ6/

Comment: @user1896653 isn't this like Image B which is not desirable?

Answer (score 0):

With :after and :before you can do that.

HTML:

```
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b"> </div>
<div class="c"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.a {
    background: #9C9E9F;
}
.b {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c9e9f, #f6f6f6);
}
.a:after, .c:before, .c:after {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.a:after {
    background: #f6f6f6;    
}
.c:before {
    background: #9c9e9f;
    left: 0;
}
.c:after {
    background: #33CCFF;
    right: 0;
    height: 80%;
}
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/9AwhF/).

Comment: Thanks. It's useful to me

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like c using CSS multiple-backgrounds.

```
div {
    background: linear-gradient(red, red),
                linear-gradient(blue, blue),
                linear-gradient(green, green);
    background-size: 30% 50%,
                     30% 60%,
                     40% 80%;
    background-position: 0% top,
                         calc(30% * 100 / (100 - 30)) top,
                         calc(60% * 100 / (100 - 40)) top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Note, you still have to use linear-gradients for background types, because CSS will not allow you to control the background-size of a single color layer. So here we just make a single-color gradient. Then you can control the size/position of each of those blocks of color independently. You also have to make sure they don't repeat, or they'll just expand and cover the whole image.

The trickiest part here is background-position. A background-position of 0% puts your element's left edge at the left. 100% puts its right edge at the right. 50% centers is middle.

For a fun bit of math to solve that, you can guess the transform is probably linear, and just solve two little slope-intercept equations.

```
// (at 0%, the div's left edge is 0% from the left)
0 = m * 0 + b
// (at 100%, the div's right edge is 100% - width% from the left)
100 = m * (100 - width) + b
b = 0, m = 100 / (100 - width)
```

so to position our 40% wide div 60% from the left, we put it at 60% * 100 / (100 - 40) (or use css-calc).

Answer (score 0):

```
background: linear-gradient(152deg , #0A64B1 60%,#0A64B1 33%,#2C3E52 45%,#2C3E52 156%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:-

In CSS file:-

```
<style>
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
    }

    .split {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 50%;
        top: 0;
    }

    .left {
        background-color: lightblue;
        left: 0;
    }

    .left h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20%;
        font-size: 90px;
    }

    .right {
        background-color: lightsalmon;
        right: 0;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 1px;
    }
</style>
```

And in body:-

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="split left">
        <h1>Welcome<br>to<br>website</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="split right">
        <h2>welcome<br>to<br>website</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <h3>copyright &copy;</h3>
</div>
</body>
```