# (CSS) Full color background transition in div

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask if there is an option to make a full color transition from for example black to white without any gradients in one element (div).

For example in this image:

[image]

I have one div element with another div inside centered in it. I wonder if it is possible to do something like this using only the background-color attribute in CSS. I know this might work using things like position attribute or using a background-image with the colors painted but I would like to try this way of doing it.

Comment: why can't it be two divs, just curious?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div

Comment: @YourConscious Because it is easier to use just one in my opinion. You don't need multiple entries in the stylesheet, only one for one div, and there is also one element less in the HTML markup. It is also easier to insert content, like text, without having to worry about things like the text not being wrapped correctly, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. Use a background gradient on the parent div and positioning to center the child:

```css
#container {
  background: #000000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml; base64, PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSI1MCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwMDAwMDAiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSI1MCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNmZmZmZmYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%, #000000), color-stop(50%, #ffffff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. Thanks for the quick answer. The reason I didn't consider gradient is because I thought it would always create some sort of grainy transition between the colors and I'm honestly suprised this is possible.

Comment: Yup, CSS gradients can create sharp borders too.

Answer (score 0):

You would still use a gradient to do this. A good tool to use is http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for this job. It would give you the following code for your gradient.

The link for the code is http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+49,ffffff+50,ffffff+100

```
background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%, #000000 49%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(49%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Link generator CSS:

[http://www.cssmatic.com](http://www.cssmatic.com/es/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28top%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28231%5C%2C56%5C%2C39%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28240%5C%2C47%5C%2C23%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2029%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28246%5C%2C41%5C%2C12%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2049%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%2890%5C%2C51%5C%2C219%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%2890%5C%2C51%5C%2C219%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B')

```css
background: rgba(231,56,39,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 29%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 49%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 50%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(231,56,39,1)), color-stop(29%, rgba(240,47,23,1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(246,41,12,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(90,51,219,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(90,51,219,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 29%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 49%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 50%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 29%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 49%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 50%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 29%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 49%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 50%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 29%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 49%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 50%, rgba(90,51,219,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e73827', endColorstr='#5a33db', GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've already worked with this site before but didn't seem to get this scenario working.

Answer (score 0):

You will be declaring 'gradient' but just to achieve your effect. Which will not be a gradient. Take a look at below. Where you will see two hard colors splitting the background of the same one `<div>`

```
.c{    
    background: #9c9e9f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%, #9c9e9f 50%, #33ccff 50%, #33ccff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(50%,#9c9e9f), color-stop(50%,#33ccff), color-stop(100%,#33ccff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c9e9f', endColorstr='#33ccff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

[**JS JIDDLER (view the bottom div, div C)**](http://jsfiddle.net/7b0nqmhf/)

*Original Source:* [How can apply multiple background color to one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the question has been already answered with a similliar solution. Thank you for the effort anyway though.