# Make background semi coloured depending on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to make a div 50% of one colour and 50% of the other colour. The colours come from a variable I grab from a json file.

So what I have is this:

// HTML

```
<div class="product 12345"> // 12345 is the id of the product
  <div class="colours"></div>
</div>
```

//Jquery

```
$.getJSON(url+'?format=json', function(data){

    $.each(data.product.custom, function(i, custom) {

      var productsHtml = [];
      $.each(custom.values, function(index, value){
        var productHtml = '' +
            '<li class="'+ (value.title).toLowerCase() +'" style="background-color:'+ (value.title).toLowerCase() +'"></li>';
        productsHtml.push(productHtml);
      });
      productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');

      $('.product.'+id+' .colours').html('<ul>'+productsHtml+'</ul>');

    });
  });
```

The `value.title` most of the times is something like "Black" or "white" etc. So then I have no problem setting a background color because i can do something like `background-color: black`. As you can see in my code.

Sometimes the `value.title` is something like "Black / pink" or "Black / White".

How can I set the background color of the li items to 50% black and 50% white?? Is there an easy way to incorporate that in the code?

Comment: Try Gradient with CSS3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window

Comment: read this also http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div

Answer (score 0):

Color-js adds lots of support for color manipulation
https://github.com/brehaut/color-js
blending two colors should look something like this:

```
var color1 = Color('#ff0000');
var color2 = Color('#00ff00');
var blend = colo1.blend(color2, 0.5);
```

If you dont want to import a library they basically just represents the colors as rpg and then calculates the average value of each color channel.

https://github.com/brehaut/color-js/blob/master/color.js