# HTML background two colors

Tags: html, css, background-color

I use this code to make the background blue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:blue;">
</body>
</html>
```

Which works good but how can I make the background have two different colors? 50% to be blue and the rest 50% to be yellow for example, split horizontally...

Comment: Please take a look to http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/

Comment: Find the answer in making two background color in css [Ckick Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a css gradient: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

```
background: linear-gradient(blue, yellow);
```

Or if you want don't want the gradual fade you have to set the position:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, blue 50%, yellow 50%, yellow 100%);
```

Comment: If anyone wants a vertical split which I found little tricky. I got this resolved ==>

.container {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    white 0%,
    white 25%,
    blue 25%,
    blue 100%
  );
}

==> html
use class='container' and put your content within it and it will automatically show 25/75 vertical split :)