# Is it possible to style 2 halves of 1 div in separately?

Tags: html, css

So for instance one half is skewed at one angle, the other is skewed at another, using only 1 div.

Reason being is that I will have text across the Div, so I can not just split it into two.

Any information or ideas that you can provide are much appreciated.

Comment: Mate, no codes, I am asking if this is possible. The question is clear enough to get an answer from someone who understands what I am asking...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can apply multiple background color to one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this as an example as you have not added any codes, it impossible to guess your approach. But you could do that by adding `background:linear-gradient` to `parent div`.

```css
div{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, green 50%);
}
div h1{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Hello !!!</h1>
</div>
```

Add `vendor prefixes` for other browser support.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have in general two different styles on one element with rule of applying under conndition, for example "apply style nr.2 if width is over 50%"

Rather than that, create some simple structure (snippet below).

!!I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS, but you can also in a limited way display 2 different colours on one div by using gradient, check this tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

But rather than that, you should do some structure, because if you need more styling than only a 2 colors, it is simply necessary.

```css
.container, .container2{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; margin:auto; width:200px; height:200px; background:black;}
.bg-1, .bg-12
{height:100%; width:50%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background:#CCF;}

.bg-2, .bg-22{height:100%; width:50%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; background:#FCC;}
.text{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; font-size:80px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; line-height:200px;}
.container2{left:230px !important;}

.bg-12{box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 52px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}
.bg-22{box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 52px 0px rgba(0,255,0,0.75);}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="bg-1"></div>
<div class="bg-2"></div>
<div class="text">
Text
</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
<div class="bg-12"></div>
<div class="bg-22"></div>
<div class="text">
Text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of elements that are not required. You should work with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, that way you'll only need 1 `div`

Comment: @Zorak Lets say I want the div's to be skewed, so that it gives the illusion of a folded piece of paper. How then would I allow both divs skewing at opposite angles and then having the text skew with it? Possible or no?

Comment: @Pefara I dont like pseudo elements because of ther behavior and a need of trimming it and figuring out their behavior.. for example, https://jsfiddle.net/w3q2fdnz/ :after element coveres the content div - OK it is after, below in structure so fine - maybe I can handle it by z-indexes? Who knows - but you have two elements, before and after .. how about to add 4 background sizes? There old fashon divs comes.

Comment: @evilgenious448 Yes, it is possible, but it come litle bit more complicated. You have to form the shape of CONTAINER, set the backgrounds and then set the container as `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @evilgenious448 and in case of SKEW, it is simplier. just skew the container and skew text in opposite way: https://jsfiddle.net/z7azopaj/