# multiple colors on progress bar with css or jquery based on width percentage

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I need to realize a progress bar with CSS, JS, or that you suggest.
I need it to be multi-color... Based on a percentage.

For example, if I've got a 50% value, the progress bar should be light blue until 30%, and green between 30 to 50%.

So, I set `style="width:xx%"` to set the percentage.

Is there a method to create multicolor progress bar?

[image]

I've tried this:

```css
.progressMulti {
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green 75%, blue 20%, red 5%);
}
```

but if set to width 50%, for example, I can see all colors... Instead it should be only light blue and green with a 50% value.

Comment: this could be done with `linear-gradient`s

Comment: i've updated the question

Comment: @Mr.Developer, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div check solution for C

Comment: you could have a background layer with your desired color scheme and the progress bar a solid black bar that shrinks according to progress

Comment: @bowl0stu i thought a easy solution...but if i don't find a easy solution, well i will apply a second layer on progressMulti.

Comment: @justMe it's not for me your solution...i need a color based on percentage...

Comment: @Mr.Developer, you can always draw 5 rectangles (black, blue, green, yellow and red) and layer them on top of eachother (blue having highest z index and black having the lowest). Blue-30%, Green-60%, yellow-95% and red 100%.

Comment: @justMe five rectangles would be needlessly tedious when we have options like `linear-gradient`

Comment: @bowl0stu, that's why I've suggested linear-gradient as a first choice

Comment: Check out this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function set_progress(_num){
 $('#progress').empty();
 var el_1_width=0;
 var el_2_width=0;
 var el_3_width=0;
 var el_4_width=0;
 if(_num>30){el_1_width=30;}else{el_1_width=_num;}
 if(_num>60){el_2_width=30;}else{el_2_width=_num-el_1_width;}
 if(_num>80){el_3_width=30;}else{el_3_width=_num-el_1_width-el_2_width;}
 if(_num>90){el_4_width=_num-90;}
 var new_font_clor='';
 if(_num<55){new_font_clor='color:black';}
 $('#progress').append('<div class="progress-text" style="'+new_font_clor+'">'+_num+' %</div>');
 $('#progress').append('<div class="progress-el" style="background-color:blue; width:'+el_1_width+'%;">&nbsp;</div>');
 $('#progress').append('<div class="progress-el" style="background-color:green; width:'+el_2_width+'%;">&nbsp;</div>');
 $('#progress').append('<div class="progress-el" style="background-color:yellow; width:'+el_3_width+'%;">&nbsp;</div>');
 $('#progress').append('<div class="progress-el" style="background-color:red; width:'+el_4_width+'%;">&nbsp;</div>');

}

set_progress(12);
```

```css
   #progress{
     border-style:solid;
     border-color:black;
     //border-width:4px;
   }
   .progress-el{
     display:inline-block;
     height:40px;
   }
   .progress-text{
     position:fixed;
     color:white;
     font-weight:bold;
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     line-height:40px;
     text-align:center;
     font-size:24pt;

   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div id="progress"></div>


 <input type="button" value="set 17%" onclick="set_progress(17);">
 <input type="button" value="set 31%" onclick="set_progress(31);">
 <input type="button" value="set 45%" onclick="set_progress(45);">
 <input type="button" value="set 67%" onclick="set_progress(67);">
 <input type="button" value="set 82%" onclick="set_progress(82);">
 <input type="button" value="set 97%" onclick="set_progress(97);">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using HTML canvas? Refer https://jsfiddle.net/y8m8pk1m/ for an example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 70, 20);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(90, 20, 50, 20);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(140, 20, 50, 20);
ctx.stroke();

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

If you are looking for a slightly complex example on this refer, https://github.com/anurag-sinha/utils/tree/master/widgets/Gauges/analog which is an Analog gauge to represent a scalar quantity (you can download and just run Analog.html in Chrome). You basically just need the colored threshold strip from  this gauge. Analog Gauge is slightly complex as it involves some arithmetic to calculate the rotation angle etc but it should be fairly simple in your case(use fillRect). You can build your widget on similar lines.