# How to divide div color with 30% different color and 70% different color in vertical using css

Tags: html, css

I want to design div tag with two color divide using css in color position 
 of div vertically divided

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    .layout {
      background-color: lightblue;
      height: 70px;
      width: 70px;
      padding: 30px;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="layout">

  </div>

  <p>This is some text.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can follow this link for applying multiple color in one div using **liner-gradient** approach. [Multi-Background-color of Single Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div)

Answer (score 0):

You can put two divisions, one with width:30% and another with width:70% in a big div with whatever width you like and give them separate background colors.
Also if you want to put a text in middle of them you can put another div in front of the other two and make its z-index more than the other divs.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    .layout {
      height: 70px;
      width: 70px;
    }
    .a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30%;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .b {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      background-color:red;
     }
  </style>

  <div class="layout">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
  </div>

  <p>This is some random text.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This One Is for Vertical Div

```css
.parent {
  height:200px;
  width:100px
}
.childA {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#0f0;
  height:30%
}
.childB {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f00;
  height:70%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="childA">
    </div>
    <div class="childB">
    </div>
</div>
```

this Is for Horizontal DIV

```css
.parent {
    height:200px;
    width:500px
}
.childA{
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  background-color:#0f0;
  height:200px
}
.childB {
  float:right;
  width:70%;
  background-color:#f00;
  height:200px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="childA">
      </div>
      <div class="childB">
      </div>
</div>
```

Run This And Try it out