# How to set double bg color out from container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need make footer like this

[image: footer]

**html**

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7 copyright__text py-3">
                COPYRIGHT TEXT
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 contact p-3">
                dsadsada dsa dasdsa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**css**

```
footer .copyright__text{
background-color: rgb(152, 181, 79);
}

footer .contact {
background-color: rgb(81, 89, 103);
}
```

Now it looks like this

[image: footer]

As you can see on first image... i need center text probably with container exactly as the text above , but bg color need be for full webpage with. With container-fluid, text is not centered correctly and is glued to the side...

Comment: **Is it only about the footer or the whole page ?** for the whole page : `body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,rgb(152, 181, 79) 55%,rgb(81, 89, 103) 55% ) center center;
}`  for the footer `.footer {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,rgb(152, 181, 79) 55%,rgb(81, 89, 103) 55% ) center center;
}`

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div/19082814](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div/19082814)

Answer (score 1):

```css
footer .copyright__text{
background-color: rgb(152, 181, 79);
}

footer .contact {
background-color: rgb(81, 89, 103);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7 copyright__text py-3">
                COPYRIGHT TEXT
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 contact p-3">
                dsadsada dsa dasdsa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Container-fluid is not solving my problem with text.

Comment: are use the bootstrap..? and which version use..?