# Linear gradient inside another linear gradient

Tags: html, css, colors, background, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a linear gradient within another linear gradient, is it possible ? example below

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #color1 50%, #color2 0%)
```

color 1 is

```
background: linear-gradient(#aa0507,#e0171e,#aa0507);
```

color 2 is

```
background: linear-gradient(#f4c05b,#fcd580,#f4c05b);
```

the end result should be this

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can apply multiple background color to one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div)

Comment: my answer doesn't solve your issue? it does exactly what needed, no? or I am missing something?

Comment: @TemaniAfif your answer causes 1px blank in the middle and responsive height issues, it's not the best solution but it works.

Comment: yes for the blank space we can easily fix it by increasing one of the gradient since it's a top/bottom direction (check the update) .. but what is the height issues? can elaborate, I would like to know and correct that issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif by increasing of the gradient, it's not 50 50% exactly, and that causes design alignment issues. for the height, I have a drop down nav bar, and when it's open it creates a blank space because the height is set to 100vh not full

Comment: can you show me example? you are probably describing another kind of gradient. In my case the gradient should be a top/bottom one with solid color. If we change this, we need to change the code. I would like to see how it's working on your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *combine* the two gradients into `background: linear-gradient(to right, #f4c05b, #fcd580, #f4c05b 50%, #aa0507 50%, #e0171e, #aa0507)` to get the effect - note that the gradients on the both left / right sections are *left to right* in this answer.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f4c05b, #fcd580, #f4c05b 50%, #aa0507 50%, #e0171e, #aa0507);
}
```

Comment: we will have the opposite direction doing this. the coloration is from top to bottom on each side.

Comment: yeah, I was pondering on that too, I'll add that to the answer

Comment: thanks @kukkuz, is it possible to make it top to bottom?

Answer (score 2):

Simply adjust the `background-position`/`background-size` using multiple background. Basically each gradient will be half width and full height.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#aa0507,#e0171e,#aa0507) right/50% 100%,
   linear-gradient(#f4c05b,#fcd580,#f4c05b) left /52% 100%; /*we can make this a little bigger to avoid the blank space*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This should be answer, it's exactly what the OP wanted.